# Double header & double mounted main screen - react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I've been having this problem for a long time and I just can't find an answer for fixing it.
[Here is an actual screenshot of what is happening.](http://g.recordit.co/4QBsB2U816.gif)

The problems are: 
1. Back button by default on Newsfeed screen
2. Double header
3. TabBar disappears when navigating to any *global screens*

The code itself:
`routes.js`

```
const RecordScreen = StackNavigator({
  Main:   { screen: Record },
  Choose: { screen: RecordChoose },
  Add:    { screen: RecordAdd }
})

const NewsfeedScreen = StackNavigator({
  Main:    { screen: Newsfeed },
  Details: { screen: NewsfeedDetails }
})

export const FriendsScreen = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Friends },
  List: { screen: FriendList }
})

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Record:   { screen: RecordScreen },
  Newsfeed: { screen: NewsfeedScreen },
  Friends:  { screen: FriendsScreen }
})

// is it correct to nest TabNavigator with StackNavigator like this?
export const LoggedIn = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Tabs },

  // global Screens
  Gallery:  { screen: Gallery },
  Profile:  { screen: Profile  },
  Settings: { screen: Settings }
})

export const LoggedOut = StackNavigator({
  Welcome: { screen: Welcome },
  SignIn:  { screen: SignIn },
  SignUp:  { screen: SignUp }
})
```

`index.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { LoggedIn, LoggedOut } from '@routes'

class Main extends Component {

  // of course is not exactly like this,
  // just an example
  state = {
    loggedIn: true
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loggedIn
      ? <LoggedIn />
      : <LoggedOut />
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

does the following change make things any better?

from:

```
export const LoggedIn = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Tabs },

  // global Screens
  Gallery:  { screen: Gallery },
  Profile:  { screen: Profile  },
  Settings: { screen: Settings }
})
```

to

```
const doNotShowHeaderOption = {
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
  },
};
export const LoggedIn = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Tabs, ...doNotShowHeaderOption, },

  // global Screens
  Gallery:  { screen: Gallery },
  Profile:  { screen: Profile  },
  Settings: { screen: Settings }
})
```

Comment: Damn, I was adding this inside the `Tabs` component! hahahha Thank you so much!!

It worked well for 1 problem! I think the other bug it's a library bug (the back button by default)
And the tabbar is disappearing when navigating to the global component

Comment: keep in mind that the navigator itself is nothing special - it is a component just like your screen and thus many of the config options that work for screens also work for navigators